# How to semantically improve this html snippet

Tags: html, semantics

Consider the following piece of markup:

```
<a href="/description/item1">
    <img src="item1.jpg">
    <footer>
        <section>
            <h2 class="title">Bar Foo</h2>
            <h3 class="subtitle">The end of the world</h3>
        </section>
        <section class="details">
            <h4 class="name">Painted by Someone</h4>
            <h5 class="id">123243552345</h5>
        </section>
    </footer>
</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gg0pfpzj/3/)

Anyway, I have always difficulties with semantics. I think that the above snippet doesn't use the elements like section/footer correct (please correct me if I'm wrong!) So I can rewrite it as:

```
<a href="/description/item1">
    <img src="item1.jpg">

    <header>
            <h2 class="title">Bar Foo</h2>
            <h3 class="subtitle">The end of the world</h3>
    </header>
    <footer>
            <h4 class="name">Painted by Someone</h4>
            <h5 class="id">123243552345</h5>
    </footer>
 </a>
```

But then again, shouldn't the anchor be (or be wrapped with) an article and is footer correct here, it is just content about the image ? Can someone help me with this piece of code and guide me through the process to make it semantically correct/better ? Any advice or documentation would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a figure with figcaption to me.

Comment: Do you need 4 levels of heading for one image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Rich Bradshaw, I would use the [figure](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp) and [figcaption](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) tags for your problem:

```
<a href="/description/item1">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/i/34/1573266.jpg" />
        <figcaption>
            <h2 class="title">Bar Foo</h2>
            <h3 class="subtitle">The end of the world</h3>
            <h4 class="name">Painted by Someone</h4>
            <h5 class="id">123243552345</h5>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
```

**figure**

> The  tag specifies self-contained content, like illustrations,
>   diagrams, photos, code listings, etc.
>
> *While the content of the  element is related to the main flow,
>   its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should
>   not affect the flow of the document.*

**figcaption**

> The  tag defines a caption for a  element.
>
> The  element can be placed as the first or last child of
>   the  element.

*> But pay attention, those are HTML 5 tags and consequently just supported in HTML 5 browsers.*